# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'DataReader'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Import the libraries

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web    
import numpy as web    
import pandas as pd    
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler    
from keras.models import Sequential    
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

## Get the stock quote

```
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2019-12-17')
```

## Show the data

```
df
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end='2019-12-17')
>         2 #Show the data
>         3 df
>
> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'DataReader'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjkOu.png)

Comment: You are importing numpy as web, overwriting pandas_datareader alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `web`.

Try:

```
import pandas_datareader as web    
import numpy as np
```